# How to make Jenkins throw an error and set build to FAILED when timeout reached?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkins Pipeline script (simplified), and I am trying to get the build to fail when the timeout is reached. How do I get the build to throw an error and set the build status to "FAILED" if the timeout limit is hit?

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'importer' }

    stages {
        stage('Import') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        timeout(time: 8, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                            sh label: 'import', script: '''
                            ssh user@server <<\'ENDSSH\'
                            cd job/folder
                            bash job.sh
ENDSSH'''
                        }
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        println error
                        error 'Timeout reached.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to make a very small change:

```
} catch (error) {
    println error
    failure(message: "Timeout reached.")
}
```

The `failure` block will fail the build with the message you specify.